# Why does this drag drop not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I am currently developing a Universal Windows Phone application, where I want a drag and drop functionality from a `ListView` to a `Canvas`.

Now I have this XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView DragItemsStarting="ListView_DragItemsStarting" CanDragItems="True">
        <Image Source="../../Assets/Images/Logo.png"/>
    </ListView>

    <ListView 
        Grid.Column="1"
        AllowDrop="True"
        Drop="Canvas_Drop"/>
</Grid>
```

This code works, but the moment I change the second `ListView` into a `Canvas`, the drop event handler no longer gets called.

Any ideas why and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background to `Transparent` and it should work.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView DragItemsStarting="ListView_DragItemsStarting" CanDragItems="True">
        <Image Source="../../Assets/Images/Logo.png"/>
    </ListView>

    <ListView 
        Grid.Column="1"
        AllowDrop="True"
        Drop="Canvas_Drop"
        Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you give any references to *why* this works? Seems like an odd thing to have to do.

Comment: @RonBeyer, from what I can tell, any dragging and dropping on a canvas without a background specified is actually picked up via the grid. (Although I'm a bit new to wpf/xaml, so without exploring further, this is all I can really tell)

Comment: @RonBeyer When a control/panel doesn't have a background, it cannot be hit tested. Then where would you drop your item to?

Comment: @JustinXL I understand it now, coming from Winforms it seemed like an odd thing, but WPF is a lot different with the way it manages the visual children, that the background is something that can be hit tested.